# luajit run error after it use much memory

Tags: lua, luajit

My program embedded `luajit`. It run well most time. Buf after is uses much memory, it began to run some logic error such as the result of `>` will be wrong.
How to find and solve the problem?

My program is use `lua`,it runs well for years. I recently change it to `luajit`.
My program is built with `gcc 4.7` and run on `debian 7`. The program build with
`-DLUAJIT_ENABLE_GC64`

```
tt = {}
for i = 1, 10000000 do
    local k = string.format( "1kkkk%d" , i )
    local v = string.format( "1vvv%d" , i )
    tt[k] = v
end
```

After the program uses much memory, it'll cause error in the near future. For example，After run the above:

```
local nNum = 10
assert( nNum > 0 )
```

the assert will run error. Other code will also run error probably. The error will appear everywhere and every code will probably run error.

Comment: Could the bug be reproduced on another machine?